# How Can I loop with array?

Tags: php

When In print_r or var_dump

```
echo "<pre>";
echo var_dump($groupname);
echo "</pre>";
```

I got the result

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#330 (1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "AAA"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#332 (1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "BBB"
  }
}
```

Now I want to got the result from the array.

```
AAA | BBB
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to start out by looking on [how arrays work](http://php.net/array). Also if you don't know "what" an array is, look over [this Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array).

**Examples from PHP.NET**

Declare an indexes and values

```
<?php
$arr = array("foo" => "bar", 12 => true);

echo $arr["foo"]; // bar
echo $arr[12];    // 1
?>
```

Here is another example with the results

```
<?php
// Create a simple array.
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
print_r($array);

// Now delete every item, but leave the array itself intact:
foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
    unset($array[$i]);
}
print_r($array);

// Append an item (note that the new key is 5, instead of 0).
$array[] = 6;
print_r($array);

// Re-index:
$array = array_values($array);
$array[] = 7;
print_r($array);
?>
```

Result of the above:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [5] => 6
)
Array
(
    [0] => 6
    [1] => 7
)
```

**Your special problem**

Now it looks to me that you want to select each name from each record / row in your array / list.

To do this you need to loop / iterate throughout the array and write the current rows name-value.

**Example on looping with arrays**

```
<?php
$people = Array(
        Array('name' => 'Kalle', 'salt' => 856412),
        Array('name' => 'Pierre', 'salt' => 215863)
        );

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($people); ++$i)
{
    echo $people[$i]['name'];
}
?>
```

**Doing this without loops**

So let's say that you know that your array only has two values, well then if you had an array looking like this:

```
$arr = array(10, 20);
```

You could write something like this to write them out:

```
echo $arr[0];
echo $arr[1];
```

Remember that when you tell your array which "row" to get, you always say "how many steps to go", meaning that if you want the first value, you take 0 steps, therefore the index is... 0!

**Object orientation and arrays**

Since you are using an object in your array you might want to check out some information about [PHP and Object Oriented Programming](http://php.net/oop).

**Side note and a cool example**

See this cool example which might give you an idea on what you can do

```
<?php

$obj = (object) array('foo' => 'bar', 'property' => 'value');

echo $obj->foo; // prints 'bar'
echo $obj->property; // prints 'value'

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done easily with foreach.

This $groupname var looks like an an array of objects. Lets have a mock class that
will create objects for our purpose.

```
class MyClass
{
 public $name = '';

 public function __construct($n)
 {
  $this->name = $n;
 }
}
```

This class has the name attribute/member in it. The $groupname is an
array as of such objects (from the var_dump)... We could create that array
like this:

```
$groupnames = Array(
        new MyClass ('AAA'), new MyClass ('BBB')
   );
```

To print out the information in that array we can use the foreach constrcut
of php.

```
foreach($groupname as $group)
{
    print "$group->name\n";
}
```

This prints the names each on a line. To have this loop output "AAA | BBB" is left
as an exercise:) Hint: You can use the "end()" construct like this
"end($group)"...

Regards,
Riza Dindir

Answer (score -3):

If you don't know, just try stuff until it works.

```
echo $groupname[0]["name"]; //probably doesnt work, next
echo $groupname[0][0]; // hmm nope
echo $groupname[0]->name; // hey this works.
```

Comment: Thank you @Les .i just try :
echo $groupname[0]["name"]; //probably doesnt work, next
echo $groupname[0][0]; // hmm nope

Comment: Understanding what you are doing is much better than just trying around.

Comment: you learn to understand by trying around, by making mistakes, at least in my opinion.

Comment: You learn by understanding why you made mistakes in the first place. Showing people how to make mistakes + showing the correct path does not help the person to understand why the first one did not work.

Comment: It was not my intention to show how to make mistakes, I tried to show how I would try and figure his problem out and come up with an answer.
I'll be more careful next time.

Comment: I would say that this is "bad programming", if you for example work with programming that approach on a follow developer is dangerous, it tend to display a certain lack fundametal understanding in languages and how to address problems. If you first do var_dump and see that it is an object, it should be obvious not to do $groupname[0][0]; because that is completely wrong. But I see your point in "try different steps" even though you failed to show that path here.